# Install ruby and use bundler with capistrano

Tags: ruby, rvm, capistrano, bundler

Meaning, with `capistrano` I want to install `ruby` (and `rvm`), some gems by means of `bundler`, and perform some tasks using them. Is this even possible? When I try to install gems with `rvm1-capistrano3` gem, it fails with this:

```
Installing light_resizer (0.2.0)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

If I make use of `capistrano-bundler` alongside above mentioned gem, setting `bundle_bins` to `[]` (to be able to install `bundler`), I can't run tasks like `deploy:assets:precompile` later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is use `capistrano-bundler` after all, but `set :bundle_bins, [:rake]`, as `rake` is all I needed. Not a perfect solution, probably, but when was it the last time it was perfect... :)